# Hi! setting ImageIcon to a Jframe and other component dont seem to work. I need help pls

Tags: java, swing, jframe, imageicon

I'm trying to set a Icon on the top left corner for my Window. but don't seem to work.. what do you think seems to be the problem?
I also tried setting an Icon and Text on an instance of JLabel but only the text came out.

The link is a screenshot for the output of the JFrame I made.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FDh6.png]

```
public class Window extends JFrame{
    
    private final int WIDTH  = 600;

    public Window(){
    // Setting the Window
        setTitle("Module Organizer");
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("checkmark-square.png");
        setIconImage(img.getImage());
        setSize(WIDTH,(WIDTH*3)/4);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // adding components
        
        add(new NavPane(), BorderLayout.WEST);
        
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't post an image of your entire desktop. Your question is about your frame so only display the frame so we can actually see what the frame looks like. If the frame icon doesn't change then it is probably because you file name is incorrect. Based on your code the image should be in the same directory as your class file. Try using `ImageIO` to read the image. You will get an error message if the image is not found. Also don't call you class "Window". There is an AWT class with that name so it is confusing. A class names should be more descriptive.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. I'll keep that in mind next time. btw, I put image file on the same directory of that class file and also check the file name and its seems fine. i'll try ImageIO as you suggest..

Comment: Also, don't edit your question using the "back" button of your browser. You just wiped out all the changes I made to your question to display the image. If you need to edit your question then first click on the "Edit" link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code

```
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 public class Window{
 JFrame f=new JFrame("Test");
 public Window(){
 JPanel j=new JPanel();

 f.setSize(1000,500);
 ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("Image.jpg");
 f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 JLabel l=new JLabel(img);
 j.add(l);
 f.add(l);
 f.setVisible(true);
}
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Window();
}
 }
```

Comment: NOTE:You can also remove the jpanel as it has no role in the answer

Comment: It still didn't work on mine.. do you think it's on the IDE?? 'cause I use vscode as my editor.. or maybe java version? cause I use java se16..

Comment: I used sublime and it worked fine

Comment: I have found the solution through ImageIO but I have to paste the whole path.. like this long `C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Codes\Java\Calculator\alert-circle.png `
is there a way to make it short?